# Crossfit without olympic weights at home gym

Tags: home-exercise, crossfit

I've started CrossFit at my gym, but now, I have to move. I can't train there anymore. I've got weights at home (dumbbells, barbell, various plates) but it's not the Olympic weights with the rubber outer coating. So now, I can't throw the weights around like they do in the videos. I've got a squat rack, bench, barbell, dumbbells, and sufficient plates. Some plates have grip slots.

Are there CrossFit routines I can do without dropping the weights? Which exercises would be good for my situation? Also, any further advise would be appreciated on how to build up a **cost effective**, dynamic and versatile home gym.

Comment: What do you mean by drop the weights? You don't have to throw the barbell after you complete the exercise... Anyway, you can buy that rubber floor you usually see in boxes/gyms.

Comment: You don't have to drop the bar, even on the Olympic lifts, you just need to practice catching the bar with your hips. Here's an example: https://youtu.be/0tPUtQCgy7Y

Answer (score 4):

The only thing that becomes impractical is performing lifts where you would normally just drop the weights like the Clean and the Snatch.  You either need to reverse the steps to set the bar down under some control or you need to perform other movements.  Another option would be to invest in the *bumper* plates (bumper plates is the technical term for the kind of plates at your box).

Your barbell and metal plates don't have to be set down gingerly, but dropping a bar from over a yard or a meter in the air will likely bend your bar.

There's still a lot you can do.  Crossfit gyms have a range of activities, but it seems that certain gyms have their favorites.  It sounds like your box favored the Olympic lifts.  Others favor powerlifting or strongman.

When working on your own, take stock of what you have and then choose a focus to push yourself towards:

- Powerlifting: primary lifts are squat, bench, deadlift
- Strongman: primary lifts would be overhead (push press), deadlift, front squat, loaded carries, etc.
- Bodybuilding: no primary lifts, but focus on getting a pump in your muscles.

With all three as a focus there's still room for metabolic conditioning (met-con), but you'll have to do barbell or dumbbell complexes that end with the bar close to the ground.  Loaded carries are another form of metabolic conditioning.

I'm currently training in a style that is somewhere between powerlifting and strongman.  I find benefit to both.  Another resource for good programming choices and helping to find direction would be [Juggernaut Training Systems](http://jtsstrength.com/).  They have a good representation from all the strength sports.